# vscode emulation in vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I use vim mode in vscode and am super happy with it. However there are times when vscode isn't available to me and I need to use vim itself. When I do, I would like my experience to be as similar as possible to vscode with vim. So, for example, I'd like to use ctrl-esc to switch tabs, ctrl-p to open files, F12 to go to a definition, etc.

Does anybody know of any pre-rolled vimrc/plugins setup that does this?